# Writing Hashmap to a file

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have an issue in writing a Hashmap to a file.

Here is the code

```java
    public HashMap<String, String> itemMap;

    public void SaveMapItem()
    {
        this.itemMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for (Item item:itemList)
        {
            itemMap.put(item.Name,item.Selected);
            Log.d(TAG,item.Name +" "+ item.Selected);
        }


        File file = new File(getDir("item", MODE_PRIVATE), "itemMap");
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            outputStream.writeObject(itemMap);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
    String Name;
    String Nickname;
    String Selected;

    public Item()
    {
        Name = "default";
        Nickname = "default";
        Selected = "false";
    }

    }
```

And here is the output (itemMap):

```
    �� sr java.util.HashMap���`� F 
    loadFactorI     thresholdxp?@     w      t 
    ITEM-00015t falset 
    ITEM-00019q ~ t 
    ITEM-00018q ~ t 
    ITEM-00002q ~ x
```

In this example, all the items should be false. I even tried using boolean as the value of the hashmap ( `HashMap<String, String>`) but they suggested I use String. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. There is no issue. 
The values are all the same and the system uses the value ~ for all the same entry.